# Problem with mouse that occurs only when playing counter strike global offensive

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, hardware, mouse

My mouse is pretty trash, it's a Logitech M175.
The battery is fairly new, but sometimes when I'm like watching a video it gets stuck (mouse presses still work though), and it stays that way until I take the battery out and put it back in.

The problem with CSGO is similar but what's different is that instead of getting stuck, it just gets as if I'm very lag heavy or the fps is super low but it's just the mouse, and it's behaving in that specific way only when I'm in csgo.

I'd like to ask if anyone has had a familiar hapenning and if there is a way to fix it? As a mouse is not something I can debug unfortunately, I'll have to handle hardware fixes to people who usually understand more than I do. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: If this is in Windows... Try disabling the "Enhance pointer precision" option.  In Windows 7, this is in Control Panel, Mouse, Pointer Options tab.  Not sure if it will help in this particular instance, but I know it can cause issues in some games.

Comment: Already done that, unfortunately it didn't do any good

Comment: Get a new mouse lol...

Answer (score 1):

Good thing i found this issue because i know exactly why that happens.
TURN OFF the logitech software. Their software is really buggy. I had same problem for long time and i couldn't find any solution for that. but i figured it out by myself... logitech software is the one causing that problem. trust me. you will love my answer :)

Comment: It might be that, but its also the usb that goes in the pc. When I have the pc turned one way, the usb is close enough. The other way? Starts working like trash.